# Heroku Running Wrong ENV Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have tried to create a QA environment for my app on Heroku.  When I deploy, the output on the console seems to suggest that the production.rb is still being run.

I created a new environment file at **/config/environments/qa.rb**. This is an exact copy of the production.rb file except I added a log statement at the top.

qa.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  puts "Loading QA Config"
```

production.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  puts "Loading Production Config"
```

Next, I ran the Heroku command to update BOTH env settings:

```
heroku config:set RACK_ENV=qa RAILS_ENV=qa --app qa-myapp
```

To double check, I print the config settings:

```
heroku config --app qa-myapp
=== qa-myapp Config Vars
...
RACK_ENV:                     qa
RAILS_ENV:                    qa
...
```

To triple check, I run the console! (notice the QA lines as well as the Rails.env):

```
heroku run console --app qa-myapp
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.8199
Loading QA Config
Loading qa environment (Rails 4.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.env
=> "qa"
```

It all seems to be done correctly.  When I push to Heroku though, it doesn't load the correct config (I added the arrow from the right to point to the log statement):

```
git push qa master
...
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
...
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (8.34s)
       Cleaning assets
       Loading Production Config <-----------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 30.6MB
-----> Launching... done, v27
       http://qa-myapp.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

What am I missing here?  I didn't think there was anything else to do in order to get this working.  Do I need to do something different here?

Comment: If it loads correctly in the Heroku console for the `qa-myapp`, it may just be how Heroku's deployment scripts are written.  Does the config look right from the console in your `qa-myapp`?

Comment: @CDub the console output for `qa-myapp` is the 2nd to last code snippet.  Is there another way to check the config from the console?

Comment: Sure - Checking the attributes in `Rails.application.config` (e.g. `Rails.application.config.logger`)

Comment: Yes, the config looks correct when I run those commands (with different env values) via the console.  I guessing that maybe the qa.rb file is load sometime after the deployment.  I just got confused seeing stuff from the production.rb file in my deployment output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "Flow" section of the [Heroku Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby) readme.  It sets `RAILS_ENV=production` on deploy for any Rails 2 / Rails 3 app.

Their documentation shows examples of how you can hack your own buildpack to change this, but if everything is working the way it should in console and through your tests, that may not be necessary (but still an option).

Comment: I logged the config values in one of my controllers and everything seems to be fine.  Thanks for the link to the Buildpack.