# Environment configuration on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create two different environments on Heroku with my RoR application, i will try to explain myself easily:

- my machine -> development environment (A)
- a free plan Heroku instance -> test environment (B)
- subscripted Heroku instance -> production environment (C)

But I can't push to (B), telling to Heroku "hey, load the "test" environment".
Surfing the net i find this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments but I don't understand why in that guide they talked about "staging" environment. I would be happy to use the 3 default ruby on rails environment: development/test/production

Do you have some suggestions?

Thanks and sorry, but I'm new about Ruby on Rails and Heroku :)

Have a nice day.

Comment: please stick to naming conventions of rails. staging is one of them. it's exactly what is described in the linked article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `test` is a special environment in the Ruby on Rails world, I'd strongly recommend avoiding using `test` as an environment name.

I've seen QA used (per another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021480/heroku-running-wrong-env-configuration) about this topic)...  But it's still outside of the convention.  So, opposed to test, Heroku's standard is `staging`, but you could use anything you want (like QA) - I'd just avoid `test`.